# Reading and Altering Drawing Tablet inputs for use in FPS games

Tags: python, input

Not an important question, I know, but just a silly side project a friend asked of me. Is there a way I can read and alter the inputs from a drawing tablet so that I can use it in a First Person Shooter game, using something like Python.

From what I know, the pen will set the mouse position to the location corresponding to the tablet, which causes you to stare at the ground and spin, verses a mouse changing the current location of the mouse, which is what a game is expecting.

My plan is to read the location of the pen compared to the last location, have the mouse moved to that location on the screen, instead of set to the location.

Any tips or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is already possible, if you change the drawing tablet input mode from absolute to relative